# Can a character have more Claw attacks than it has limbs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon

In Pathfinder there are numerous ways of obtaining 2x Claw Attack, such as Lesser Rage Totem, Feral Mutagen, alternate racial traits of Tieflings etc.

However, it seems that by specialising in getting claw attacks one could have 6+ Claw natural attacks while having only two hands and two legs. I guess the same would hold for bite or gore attacks.

RAW doesn't seem to mention that, but how about RAI?

Also, how does Rake monster special ability, that can be obtained with Beastform Alchemist interact with existing Claw attacks? Rake states that it grants additional Claw attacks, but can they be used at any time or only while grappling/pouncing, since there are separate Claw attacks listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing about this in RAW, as you suspect.

This was discussed on the [paizo boards](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mpnk?Limit-of-natural-attacks-per-limb) as well. The closest rule you get is from the [Eidolon Claw Evolution](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Claws-Ex-):

> Claws (Ex): An eidolon has a pair of vicious claws at the end of its limbs, giving it two claw attacks. [...] This evolution can be selected more than once, but the eidolon **must possess an equal number of the limbs evolution**.

If weird outsiders that can resemble anything the Summoner's player can think of can't have multiple claws per arm, a point can be made that "normal" creatures also can't.

Rake is a different thing. Rake allows you to make 2 free claw attacks during a grapple, in addition to whatever you do in the grapple, including regular claw attacks.

> Rake (Ex): A creature with this special attack gains extra natural attacks under certain conditions, typically when it grapples its foe. **In addition to the options available to all grapplers**, a monster with the rake ability gains **two free claw attacks** that it can use only against a grappled foe.

The Beastmorph Alchemist gains Rake without a Claw specified, so you can use any claws you possess (if you have multiple limbs) for the ability.

Comment: About that last paragraph: in my question I assumed I already got some claw attacks and then ended up with Rake on top of them. Pounce says you can make a full-round attack during charge, including your Rake, so what then?

Comment: @eimyr If you pounce, you get one attack per claw, plus 2 attacks with any claw from Rake.